What does valid_lft and preferred_lft mean in `ip address`
When I run ip address I see a line like this for my ethernet connection for IPv4:
inet 12.34.56.78/18 brd 12.34.65.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno2
   valid_lft 475sec preferred_lft 475sec

On all the other interfaces, it is valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever.
Is this valid lifetime and preferred lifetime? What do they mean in this context, and shouldn't they be forever?

They're originally IPv6 parameters that were re-used by some IPv4 DHCP clients.

"Valid" lifetime defines how long the address may be used at all. This directly maps to the DHCP lease lifetime.

"Preferred" lifetime defines how long the address should be chosen as a source address for outbound connections (allowing gradual deprecation of an address prefix). DHCP doesn't have such a concept in IPv4, so it's set to equal the valid lifetime.


